# Websockets for Embedded Application

Tags: microcontroller, home-automation, website

I need to clear out my doubts regarding my Home Automation project.
I am working on project based on IoT Home Automation project. There are three entities in this project:

1. Web Server
2. Embedded Client
3. Android App

Android App will send data to Web server to ON/OFF switch on Embedded Client. Server Receive data and decide to send to which client. Server send data to appropriate client and get feedback and send back to the Android APP.

Multiple Embedded Client can be controlled by Single Application.

Now I have decided to use the Websocket Protocol, As using WS I can make server-Client communication realtime and Avoid polling/Long polling.

But as I have studied about WS more, I found it is not secure and easy to hack. 
Please guide me which technology should I use for this project, and what should be server and client requirements to fulfill the objective of the project.

Comment: If it's only for sending ON/OFF and a response, why do you need it to be always connected? You could setup servers on the embedded systems.

Comment: if I set up server on Embedded system I have to open my router. If I go for static IP it costs me higher, and if I go for multiple System then it is not a practical way. The practical way is to connect your embedded system to a server and get data that's what IoT do.

Answer (score 2):

I recently did a similar design for fun with an iphone sending http requests to a webserver running on a MSP430.  I also looked a little at security.  I think if you want to make your project "more secure and not easy to hack" then you should look into encrypting whatever communication channel you are using.  I'm sure you could encrypt the payload you send from the android phone, and decrypt on your endpoint.

The problem I hit was the code to support something like https key negotiating was way too big for my little device.  I ended up going with their built in AES encryption engine, and just sharing the keys between the devices ahead of time.

In any event that's where I would start, once you can encrypt your payload, your transport mechanism starts to matter less and less.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try Zig-Bee Module.
One Of the Best For Home Automation.
You can Buy A Zig-Bee Module around $34 Interfacing it is Pretty easy Using 
Keil  Softwares Already Present in the Market.

Or

Using Your Current Model Create Algorithm For Creating Ciphers,As Only You Know How your Ciphers No One can Hack Them,Later Decode Them At the Receiving End.
I think you must have used php sockets for opening connection ,i wonder how are you recognizing the clients.
And how Will The response to your Android presuming that is the client being identified by the unique Ip Address, Help IN Your Automation.